# When is the union of two chart domains a chart domain?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Given a smooth manifold $M$, call an open set $A \subseteq M$ a *chart domain* iff there exists a chart $(U,\Phi)$ in the maximal atlas on $M$ such that $A=U.$

> **Question.** If I've got two chart domains $A,B \subseteq M$, what conditions do I need on the intersection $A \cap B$ before I can conclude that $A \cup B$ is itself a chart domain?

Comment: Do you have a counter-example if $A \cap B$ is connected ?

Comment: I can't think of one. But I'm pretty new to this, so don't take that too seriously.

Comment: Simply connected is also required: in $S^2$, take as charts $S^2$ minus north pole and $S^2$ minus south pole.

Comment: And *domain of chart* can be better.

Comment: There is no reason to expect any interesting condition (besides a tautological one or $A\cap B=\emptyset$). For instance, even contractibility (or even being diffeomorphic to $R^n$) of $A\cap B$ does not suffice.